# Not being prompted to "Erase Disk and Install eOS" during setup

Tags: system-installation

During installation from USB stick on W10 machine, [image: I do not see this screen:]

Rather, it skips right to the partition creation screen and clicking "change" or "+" or "add partition" just makes the installation hang. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Tony

Answer (score 1):

If this happens, you can run the live version of elementary OS, delete partitions and format drives using gparted then try again. This worked for me.